# FTP account for NGINX on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ftp, amazon-ec2, sftp

I'd like to use FileZilla to connect to my domain that runs off NGINX on my Amazon Linux EC2 instance.

The default ec2-user has no write permissions. I can chmod a folder by switching to root in SSH, but this isn't very safe, takes a lot longer and is not very efficient.

Does anyone know how I can setup an FTP for the domain itself so I can transfer files like I would in say, a cPanel setup on Apache?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check this article

Set up an FTP server on Amazon AWS EC2 http://lzw-programmingjourney.blogspot.com/2011/12/set-up-ftp-server-on-amazon-aws-ec2.html

Thanks